# Dynamical file names for loop and thread in jmeter

Tags: csv, jmeter, automated-tests, load, performance-testing

I have created a script for simple scenario register and login to app with 30 users (threads). Here to register and login, file name(register.csv) has configured on csv data set. 
[image: CSV data set config for thread]

Now to test the reliability, I have to run this script for 10 times. I have created 10 files naming `register1.csv`, `register2.csv`, ... `register10.csv`. and I have one file called loop.csv and it has all 10 files names. For each thread group one file name has to be taken from loop csv data set.. 
[image]
but its not working.

How could I resolve this problem?

Comment: Could You clarify why do you want to have 10 different files? If you have one file all together and you do your loop you will read new values from it in every thread. (It is possible though to add different files to different threads, the easiest solution is probably having a code snippet included in the 10 different thread groups.)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Execution Order](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) JMeter User Manual chapter:

> 1. Configuration elements
> 2. Pre-Processors
> 3. Timers
> 4. Sampler
> 5. Post-Processors (unless SampleResult is null)
> 6. Assertions (unless SampleResult is null)
> 7. Listeners (unless SampleResult is null)

It means that second CSV Data Set Config is initialized **before** than `${file}` variable is being evaluated so you won't be able to use 2 CSV Data Set Config elements when one depends on another. I would recommend switching to [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) instead which can evaluate filename from JMeter Variable on the fly:

[image: JMeter CSVRead Function]

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article to get familiarized with JMeter Functions concept.